# How to search for text and filter?

Tags: redis, redisearch, redis-om-spring

***UPDATE: This is fixed in 0.8.0***

I am trying to search for filter by an indexed field and search for free text inside my objects. It seems that it is searching for the company name ***or*** the search term. How do I make this an ***and*** for [SearchStream.freeText(String freeText)](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring/blob/main/redis-om-spring/src/main/java/com/redis/om/spring/search/stream/SearchStream.java#L21)?

*I need to use SearchStream.freeText since there are many fields I want to search on.*

My data based on the [roms-documents](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring/tree/v0.6.4), I modified [RomsDocumentsApplication](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring/blob/v0.6.4/demos/roms-documents/src/main/java/com/redis/om/documents/RomsDocumentsApplication.java)

```
companyRepo.deleteAll();
Company redis1 = Company.of("Redis", "wwwabccom", new Point(-122.066540, 37.377690), 526, 2011, Set.of(CompanyMeta.of("Redis", 100, Set.of("RedisTag"))));
Company redis2 = Company.of("Redis", "wwwxyzcom", new Point(-122.066540, 37.377690), 526, 2011, Set.of(CompanyMeta.of("Redis", 100, Set.of("RedisTag"))));

Company microsoft1 = Company.of("Microsoft", "wwwabcnet", new Point(-122.066540, 37.377690), 526, 2011, Set.of(CompanyMeta.of("Redis", 100, Set.of("RedisTag"))));
Company microsoft2 = Company.of("Microsoft", "wwwxyznet", new Point(-122.066540, 37.377690), 526, 2011, Set.of(CompanyMeta.of("Redis", 100, Set.of("RedisTag"))));


companyRepo.save(redis1);
companyRepo.save(redis2);
companyRepo.save(microsoft1);
companyRepo.save(microsoft2);


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Document
@ToString
public class Company {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @NonNull
  @Indexed
  private String name;
```

If I search, my first two searches seem fine, but my third search find values not for the company ***Microsoft***, but for ***Redis***

```
var result1 = entityStream.of(Company.class)
        .filter(Company$.NAME.eq("Redis"))
        .filter("*abc*")
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Search1:");
result1.forEach(System.out::println);

var result2 = entityStream.of(Company.class)
        .filter(Company$.NAME.eq("Microsoft"))
        .filter("*xyz*")
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Search2:");
result2.forEach(System.out::println);

var result3 = entityStream.of(Company.class)
      .filter(Company$.NAME.eq("Microsoft"))
      .filter("*co*")
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Search3:");
result3.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output of the program:

**Search1:**

Company(id=01GR46XB7BMJXV5WK3AJ3FA4M9, name=Redis, tags=[], url=wwwabccom,
Company(id=01GR46XB974C3JJDAW70N20SFV, name=Microsoft, tags=[], url=wwwabcnet,

**Search2:**

Company(id=01GR46XB9388CRW0P71QM45K43, name=Redis, tags=[], url=wwwxyzcom,
Company(id=01GR46XB9ABBV3TN9BTQFP08C1, name=Microsoft, tags=[], url=wwwxyznet,

**Search3:**

Company(id=01GR46XB7BMJXV5WK3AJ3FA4M9, name=***Redis***, tags=[], url=wwwabccom,
Company(id=01GR46XB9388CRW0P71QM45K43, name=***Redis***, tags=[], url=wwwxyzcom,

I start redis with

```
docker run -d --name redis-stack -p 6379:6379 -p 8001:8001 redis/redis-stack:6.2.6-v2
```

> module list

```
127.0.0.1:6379> module list
1) 1) "name"
   2) "timeseries"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 10805
2) 1) "name"
   2) "graph"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 21005
3) 1) "name"
   2) "ReJSON"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 20403
4) 1) "name"
   2) "search"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 20604
5) 1) "name"
   2) "bf"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 20403
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.redis.om</groupId>
  <artifactId>redis-om-spring</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Turns out this is just a bug that is now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple.

The order of the filter matters. If you search in this order the first filter is ignored.

```
var result3 = entityStream.of(Company.class)
      .filter(Company$.NAME.eq("Microsoft"))
      .filter("*co*")
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Search3:");
```

If you switch the filter it works flawlessly

```
var result4 = entityStream.of(Company.class)
        .filter("*co*")
        .filter(Company$.NAME.eq("Microsoft"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Search4:");
result4.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I found this out by placing a break point on [io.redisearch.client.Client](https://github.com/RediSearch/JRediSearch/blob/v2.2.0/src/main/java/io/redisearch/client/Client.java#L374)
Somehow for *Search3* the filter on Company name is missing, but is present for *Search4*.

Added a [bug report](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring/issues/176).

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the output of `modules list` from the CLI? I suspect this has to do with Redis' rules for tokenization/Escaping  https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/escaping/ and prefix https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/query_syntax/#prefix-matching and infix/suffix matches https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/query_syntax/#infixsuffix-matching

Comment: thanks, I have added modules list in the question.